# Android Bluetooth disconnected

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a piece of code that detects if I'm receving a call then my app stops playing music and resume playing. I want to do the same if any bluetooth device is disconnected from my device, i want it to stop playing as well. I'm not sure where to begin, please help me. Thank you.

Here is my code for incoming calls:

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state){ 

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                      
               //CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            if (audioOncall) {
                resetMetadata();
                UpdatetoLogo();
                Intent restart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(restart);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
               //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            if (audioOncall) {
                resetMetadata();
                UpdatetoLogo();
                Intent restart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(restart);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
               //CALL_STATE_RINGING
            audioOncall = audioSignal.isPlaying();
            stopOncall();
                break;
           default:
                break;


        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }
};
```

I have managed to get bluetooth to work, but it's not listening to changes activity, it only pick up whatever the state was when the app loaded... how do I change the below code to make it listen for the changes in the `bluetooth` activity?

```
public void onCreate() {

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
}

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
           //Device found
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            //Device is now connected
            stopOncall();

            resetMetadata();
            UpdatetoLogo();
            Intent restart = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(restart);
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            //Done searching
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
           //Device is about to disconnect
            stopOncall();
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
           //Device has disconnected
            stopOncall();
        }           
    }
};
```